# MongoDB query for multiple fields in a collection

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to query for multiple fields in a collection that looks like:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54ee37f3a4cd7c1ce4483124"), "imageblock" : "http://someimage.jpg", "textblock" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in eget aliquam, odio ut leo mi turpis a felis, adipiscing neque maecenas ac nulla nec curabitur. A hac neque magnis integer arcu ut, per bibendum, aliquet metus nec ante orci amet. Feugiat quis sit" }
```

What would be the best approach to retrieve the values for both the "imageblock" and "textblock" keys? Very new to working with MongoDB.

```
Mongo mg = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
DB db = mg.getDB("deepdivedb");
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("contentblocks");
DBCursor cursor = collection.find();

try {

    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(cursor.next().get("imageblock"));                  
    }

} finally {
    cursor.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the names of the keys you want to access, you can do something as follows inside your try/catch block.

```
while (cursor.hasNext()) {

    DBObject document = cursor.next();

    System.out.println(document.get("imageblock"));
    System.out.println(document.get("textblock"));
}
```

Comment: Ahh, I was close. That did it. Many Thanks